# NDK linking library with cmake

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I have a c++ library which does opengl (es 2.0) rendering and I want to use it on android. When linking the library with `target_link_libraries(mylib log GLESv2)` I receive the following error:

```
ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory
ld: error: cannot open crtend_so.o: No such file or directory
ld: error: cannot find -llog
ld: error: cannot find -lGLESv2
ld: error: cannot find -lm
ld: error: cannot find -lstdc++
ld: error: cannot find -lm
ld: error: cannot find -ldl
ld: error: cannot find -lc
ld: error: cannot find -ldl
```

If I provide a specific directory from android ndk manually it works. In cmake this looks similar to this:

```
link_directories( ${ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/${ANDROID_API}/arch-${ANDROID_ABI}/usr/lib )
```

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to solve the error.
In this simple [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-gl2/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt) the additional definition of link_directories is not needed. What is the difference to my library?

Comment: Weird.  Almost as if it's not using the correct compiler tooling.  Are you using gradle to build or using cmake/make directly?

Comment: If you are using Android Gradle Plugin + CMake externalNativeBuild{ ... }, there should be no such wrong path issue. Because the gradle+cmake tool chains will look for the correct link directories path `${ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/${ANDROID_API}/arch-${ANDROID_ABI}/usr/lib`.

Comment: I am using Android Studio to compile. Perhaps something in my cmake file is overwriting what Android is providing? How can I check which link directories android is providing?

Comment: Use verbose mode if it helps `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)`. Need to set path for code using `include_directories`. Share your CMake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for this was quite simple. I was overwriting the compiler flags in my cmake files:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-foo" )
```

when I changed this to

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -foo" )
```

the linking problems are gone.